# How to direct the generated PDF to download instead of preview?

Tags: php, fpdi

I am successfully generating a PDF by using fpdf and fpdi libraries. The problem is that *$pdf->Output(); line opens the pdf for preview whereas I have been asked to let it download by default. Though I can change my own browsers' settings to force to download but i can not force the users of the page to do those settings. I can show my code if required. Please help!

Thanks,

baburman

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I figured out.

Just provide parameters to output method like this:

*$pdf->Output("filenametodownload.pdf", 'D');*

It works for chrome, firefox, internet explorer and safari.